# Looking for a good way to write an if structure with multiple possibilities

Tags: python

I'm using if statements to retrieve something from the db. But it has multiple conditions and my current implementation works but looking for better options.

```
data = get(col1=a,
           col2=b,
           col3=c
           )

if not data:
#fall to 2nd option
    data = get(col1=a,
           col2=b
            )

if not data:
#fall to 3rd option
    data = get(col1=a,
           col3=c
            )

if not data:
#fallback to 4th option
    data = get(col1=a
            )
```

The get function has code to retrieve rows from mysql database. Is there a better way in python to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit cleaner, and you can easily add new cases to it:

```
args = [dict(col1=a,col2=b,col3=c),
        dict(col1=a,col2=b),
        dict(col1=a,col3=c),
        dict(col1=a)]
for arg_dict in args:
    data = get( **arg_dict )
    if data:
        break
```